# How to format data to specific format

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a local data which is in following format ..

```
var data = [["Local", 75], ["STD", 55], ["ISD", 96], ["VOIP", 123], ["INCOMING", 34], ["INET", 104]];
```

Now i want this data to be from database.Here is my database data and this is in json format.

```
var data2= [{"type":"Local","value":"100"},{"type":"STD","value":"200"},{"type":"ISD","value":"234"},{"type":"VOIP","value":"500"},{"type":"INCOMING","value":"234"},{"type":"INET","value":"123"}]
```

but i am not able to use this data as this format is not same as my local data ..

So my question is how to convert this to my local data format.
Please help.

How to convert `var data2` to `var data` format.

Comment: 'Here is my database data and this is in json format' -- that's not JSON format.

Comment: @jlarson sir this is my parsing code..Please see post

Comment: @jlarson Please help me sir to convert database data to json formate

Comment: JSON.parse turns a string containing JSON into a JavaScript object.  So you actually have JSON already in the `dbdata.d` string

Comment: Hey! Can you explain your question little bit more. It's not clear much to give an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `map()` function:

```
var parsedData = JSON.parse(data2);
data = parsedData.map(function (o) { return [o.type, Number(o.value)]; });
console.log(data);
```

Comment: Sir How to convert var data2 to var data formate.Please help

Comment: I have modified the code as `Number(o.value)` since data will have  `["STD", 55]`  the second part in the array is of number type whereas your previous code will return `["STD", "55"]`

Answer (score 0):

This is not a valid JSON.
A valid one looks like

```
[{"type":0,"value":0},{"type":1,"value":2},{"type":2,"value":4},{"type":3,"value":6},{"type":4,"value":8}]
```

You can verify the same on http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: He posted output of `console.log(data);` in browser console. This is valid json!

Comment: @Didar_Uranov Up voted. yes dude. You are right. I think That question is need to be more clear.